# I have to write a program which accepts n number of integers and display the degree of the array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to code this for the last hour but I keep on getting "segmentation error". I'm still very new to C so please don't be too harsh. Can anybody help?

Here is my code:

input:4 2 4 2 2 5 6
output: 3

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int degreeOfArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    int maxnum = -100000;
    int currentN = 0;
    int res;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        currentN = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                currentN++;
            }
        }
        if(currentN > maxnum) /*if the current is greater than max, current is max*/
        {
            maxnum = currentN;
            res = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    argv++;
    int n = argc - 1;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", degreeOfArray(arr, n));
}
```

Comment: What does the input to the program look like?

Comment: my bad, input:4 2 4 2 2 5 6       output: 3

Comment: `argv[i + 1]`... but you already did `argv++` before.

Comment: Please include that in your question, and also show the exact error you get when you run the program

Comment: should I remove argv++ then?

Comment: when I run the program locally , all I get is "segmentation fault", also I have added the input/output above. thanks

Comment: Your `degreeOfArray` function will return `2` instead of `3` for the given input

Comment: @smac89 could you show me how to fix this if you don't mind?

Comment: Should you return `maxnum` instead of `res`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja correct, fixed now , thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't deface your question after accepting an answer. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: To fix the issue I highlighted, you just need to return `maxnum` instead of `res`. Also think of what happens of the array is empty; then the function will return `-10000` instead of `0`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of naughty:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    argv++;
    int n = argc - 1;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", degreeOfArray(arr, n));
}
```

- Argc is 4.
- You increment argv (which is naughty).
- n is 3.
- arr has values [0] through [2]
- You loop from 0..2 (which is fine)
- You set arr[i] just fine, but the call atoi(argv[i+1]) is a problem.

`I` is going to reach 2. so you're hitting `argv[3]`. Which would be fine if you hadn't incremented `argv`.

So either get rid of the `i+1` there or don't increment `argv`.

Comment: so I changed atoi(arg[i + 1]) to atoi(arg[I]). its no longer giving me segmentation error but its printing 2 instead of the correct answer 3.

Comment: Why do you think it should print 2? You're printing the NUMBER that is max, not the COUNT of that number.